# Adding Strings to List with the number of a certain letter in them increasing

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

So I have two int's `v` and `w`, a string `q`, and a list `list`.
I need to make it so that `list` adds a string with a duplication of `q`, ranging from `v` through `w`.

For example: v is 2, w is 4, q is "a".
list should be [aa, aaa, aaaa] by the time the program is done.

I have done various programs similar to this, and I felt like this would be easy, and I still think it is but for some reason I am missing something. I have attempted to solve this by doing

```
for (int j = v; j <= w; j++) {
    String s = "";
    for (int k = 0; k < j ; k++) {
        s+=q;
    }
    list.add(s);
}
```

But that just gives a constant number of Qs. Not changing.

Comment: Your code looks right to me.  If your code is not giving the correct output, please give us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we could run and reproduce the incorrect output.

Comment: Well he's going to get qq, qqq, qqqq

Comment: When you say: *q is "a". list should be [qq, qqq, qqqq]* - Do you mean that the list should be `["aa", "aaa", "aaaa"]`? I'm pretty sure that's what you mean.

Comment: Now I'm really confused.  You said `q` was `"a"`, but you said the list should be `[qq, qqq, qqqq]` instead of `[aa, aaa, aaaa]`--and now it's giving you X's?  Where are the X's coming from?  Has your program been invaded by some other StackOverflow post?  Please focus on creating a complete test program that we can compile and run.

Comment: You are printing the code out with list.get(0) repeatedly, because this function works. You didn't iterate through the list, but printed the first entry list.size() times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, prefer `StringBuilder` to `String` concatenation (that *pollutes* the `intern` cache for one). And you need to begin by looping `v` times to create your initial `String`; then append `q`. Something like

```
int v = 2;
int w = 4;
String q = "a";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
    sb.append(q);
}
for (int j = v; j <= w; j++) {
    list.add(sb.toString());
    sb.append(q);
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Output is (as requested)

```
[aa, aaa, aaaa]
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: I'm wondering why String concatenation was polluting the intern cache. It was my understanding only constant Strings where interned implicitly

Comment: Perhaps I should have said *may* pollute the intern cache (it's really up to the runtime). Regardless, using `s+=q;` for `String` concatenation in an inner loop is going to create a lot of useless temporary references.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

You're screwing something else up. This works fine.

For the record my prediction is: "You are printing the code out with list.get(0) repeatedly, because this function works. You didn't iterate through the list, but printed the first entry list.size() times."

```js
var list = []

var v = 2;
var w = 4;
var q = "a"


for (var j = v; j <= w; j++) {
    var s = "";
    for (var k = 0; k < j ; k++) {
        s = s + q;
    }
    list.push(s);
}
document.write(list)
```

Comment: just converted the ints to vars and fed the same function in there. Only for the JS Fiddle, Not sure you could do any quick runnable fragment other than javascript. But, you can see the function is the same. And the output is what is expected.

Comment: I can read the javascript just fine -- but I keep getting a, aa, aaa, aaaa

Comment: Mine gives "aa,aaa,aaaa" as the output, as requested. You are getting "a" for the first entry?

Comment: That means somethings askew with the variables set before OP's outer loop since it's iterating 4 times instead of 3.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved -- the issue was with improper values regarding v & w. Thank you to all who answered or contributed, I will keep these new techniques in mind for the future.

Answer (score -1):

It can be done using [StringUtils.repeat](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#repeat(java.lang.String,%20int))

```
for (int j = v; j <= w; j++) {
   list.add(StringUtils.repeat("q", j));
}
```

There is also one another way of doing it using native android code and in one line instead of using two loops

```
for (int j = v; j <= w; j++) {
  list.add(String.format(String.format("%%%ds", j), " ").replace(" ","q"));
}
```

Comment: I'd guess it doesn't address the question and asks we add a library to just condense the code that should already work.

Comment: Probably because you're not solving the problem.  The OP says that his code isn't working.  What you've done is given him a nicer way to do what his code already does.  But if his code isn't working, this won't fix it.  So you've pretty much answered the wrong question.  I'm not the downvoter, but I'm guessing that's why.